# Navigation Buttons Lost in Storyboard App

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationbar

I am trying to debug an iOS app which is using Storyboards. When the problem scene is first displayed it is correct, like so:

[image: Correct Navigation]

When I navigate through to the next scene by tapping one of the buttons such as "Any Category" and then navigate back again, the navigation buttons are gone like so:
[image: Incorrect Navigation]

I have not been able to find an obvious cause for this change. Is there something in particular I should be looking for that may be modifying the navigation bar? Perhaps there is some automatic handling by the storyboard process that needs to be disabled?

Here is part of the storyboard to provide context:
[image: Storyboard]

I have also found that if I add a back button explicitly to the navigation bar and segue handling code, it does work but no chevron is displayed to indicate that it navigates back.

Code added in viewDidLoad:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:backArrowString style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backBtnClicked:)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBtnItem;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
```

and associated action:

```
-(IBAction)backBtnClicked:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: What Segue type are you using?

Comment: [self.navigationController.viewControllers count] check the count is it greater than 0

Comment: Where the back button on the first screen leads? A picture of your storyboard may be useful.

Comment: @Raghav [self.navigationController.viewControllers count] returns 2

Comment: @Crazyrems added storyboard and segue screenshot.

Comment: @zorro2b: How did you navigate back ? Can you add that code ?

Comment: @MidhunMP this code was not written by me. From my understanding the navigation back is handled automatically by the storyboard. I see no code that manages the navigation back.

Comment: @zorro2b: I'm not seeing any segue or connection back in your storyboard

Comment: @MidhunMP I am not sure what you expect to see? I created a new project as a test with a navigation controller and two view controllers. I wrote no code and navigation worked as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's probably happening is the the view controller the buttons navigate to is breaking the navigation stack;  the destination view controller to which the app segues after pressing, say "Any Category," is using the navigation controller in a non-standard way.

Take a look at the destination view controller.  If it's intended to work correctly with the navigation controller system, it should not be pushing, popping, segue-ing, or initiating any other form of navigation itself.

What does the destination view controller do?

Comment: Both view controllers are using performSegueWithIdentifier to navigate from the content of their uiscrollview to the next view. Investigating your theory, I ripped almost all of the code out of the destination view controller and the navigation bar began behaving correctly! However I have traced it to prefersStatusBarHidden returning YES in the destination controller. Once this is removed the navigation works correctly. I am not sure if this could just be another symptom of the problem you have outlined? What is the correct way to handle navigation from within a scrollview?

Comment: What action initiates the navigation? Is it tapping on a view inside scrollView? You can use performSegueWithIdentifer to go forward, but you need to use [self.navigationController popViewController] to go back. How is the back navigation currently handled?

Comment: Yes, tapping in the scrollview to go forward and it is using popViewControllerAnimated to return. Seems it should be ok. I will accept this answer as it has been the most helpful, although I still don't understand the root cause.

Comment: You could try simplifying the navigation by *only* using the back button in the nav bar and disabling whatever is calling popViewController. That would change the user experience a little, but it might be more consistent.